# yiic.php works but not yiic in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, yii

I'm going to my **Yii** project **protected** folder in **Ubuntu command line** and types:

> yiic help

it returns:

> yiic: command not found

But when I type:

> php yiic.php help

it works properly.

`php yiic` works too. Only problem when I type yiic without php. `yiic` file has permission `775` and `php-cli` installed.

What I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

It works with:

> ./yiic

But I don't know what it means?

Comment: Try ./yiic at the root

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It simply means that your project `protected` folder is not in your [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) environment variable.

**Modify PATH**

Here is a simple command to add a folder in `PATH` :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/framework
```

You should add yii framework folder (the real `yiic` command is here), not your project protected folder.

**Or use a Symlink**

If you don't want to modify your `PATH`, you could create a symlink in `/usr/bin` :

```
ln -s /path/to/framework/yiic /usr/bin/yiic
```

Comment: Thanks for full answer. So If I want to call `yiic` with full path I need to do `/path/to/protected/./yiic`?

Comment: If you don't want to modify your PATH or create a symlink, simply use `/path/to/protected/yiic` or `/path/to/framework/yiic`, or `./yiic` if you are in one of these folders.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running windows, no need for any %PATH% variable, just fallow these steps:

1. When you download the Yii from the website, there is a folder called
   `framework` inside the rar file you downloaded. Copy that folder to
   your webserver root directory, which is in my case `C:\wamp\www`.
2. In the `www` folder also create a new folder called `NewYiiApp`.
   Inside this folder your new Yii application will be created and here you will write your controllers, models and
   classes.
3. After that open your cmd using Start->Run->cmd.
4. Using CMD navigate to the `framework` folder using cd
   `C:/wamp/www/framework`.
5. Open Windows Explorer and naigate to the PHP directory. In my case
   it is located in `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13`
6. Ensure that this folder contains php.exe file
7. Paste the following line in the already opened CMD
8. `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.exe yiic webapp
   C:/wamp/www/NewYiiApp`, but change my PHP folder path with yours
9. It will ask you: Create a web application under
   `C:/wamp/www/NewYiiApp`? Type Yes and hit ENTER.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Modify $yiic path

```
$yiic=dirname(__FILE__).'/../yii_framework/framework/yiic.php';
```

then set permission to 777 by: sudo chmod 777